# Google Play Services issues

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-play, admob

I am using cordova latest version, gradle latest version and everything latest version.
I couldn't understand how or where update this
Can you tell me how to fix it, I'm a beginner and I don't understand
when I uploading my game in the play store, it says this

> Your latest production release (10001 (1.0.1)) contains SDK issues
>
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:15.0.1 This SDK version
> has been reported as outdated. Upgrade to a newer version (19.3.0+).
>
> Starting from July 29, 2023 00:00 (UTC) you won't be able to release
> new versions which contain this SDK version.
>
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1 This SDK version has
> been reported as outdated. Upgrade to a newer version (19.3.0+).
>
> This SDK version has a note from the SDK developer. Here's what the
> SDK developer told us:
>
> This version is officially deprecated, and will soon disable ad
> loading. Please update to a new version. See
> https://developers.google.com/admob/android/deprecation for more
> details.
>
> Starting from July 29, 2023 00:00 (UTC) you won't be able to release
> new versions which contain this SDK version.

i find this codes in my cordova project

\platforms\android\app\build.gradle

`// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib")) implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1" // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END`

and in the cordova plugin as well

\plugins\cocoon-plugin-ads-android-admob\plugin
 `<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"/> <dependency id="cocoon-plugin-ads-android-common"/>`

15.0.1 is written everywhere

I use these plugins

```
    <plugin name="cocoon-plugin-ads-android-admob" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-bb-nativeaudio" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-nativeaudio" />
```

Comment: What plugin are you using? Post your config.xml

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I use these

 <plugin name="cocoon-plugin-ads-android-admob" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-bb-nativeaudio" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-nativeaudio" />